# Vim replacing tabs with double spaces

Tags: vim, indentation

So I've written some code of an assignment and i forgot the universities policy of
indent with 2spaces.

Normally I'ld have put a:
`//vim: ts=2:tw=78: et:`

at the top of my files, but this time I forgot.

How should I go about replacing all tabs with 2 space?
would 
s/[TAB]/[SPACE][SPACE]
work?
 (replacing [TAB] and [SPACE] with the respective key presses for the characters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a look at `retab`.
First set `tabstop`, `shiftwidth` and `expandtab`, then use the `retab` command: it will reformat all your file with the desired format.

Comment: Watch for literal tabs that are not indenting, that is, are not at the beginning of line. From :h :retab
"Careful: This command modifies any <Tab> characters inside of strings". It means that "\tFoo\tBar" becomes "  Foo  Bar"

Comment: I fround oput that if i just add the vim setting stuff the the to, the when i reopen the file, vim will automatically call retab even.
Thankyou

Answer (score 9):

> How should I go about replacing all tabs with 2 space?

You can do

```
:%s/\t/  /g
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands:

```
:set expandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
:retab!
```

Check out my screencast on tidying whitespace here: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/.